# Changing web service url in SUDS library

Tags: python, soap, suds

Using SUDS SOAP client how do I specify web service URL. I can see clearly that WSDL path is specified in Client constructor but what if I wan't to change web service url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suds supports [WSDL with multiple services or multiple ports](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#WSDLWITHMULTIPLESERVICESMULTIPLEPORTS) (or both), and without having any detailed information on what you're working with, I am only *guessing* that this is what you are looking for. This question would be easier to answer if you provided more detail, such as what your `Client` instance looks like.

After you have successfully constructed a `Client`, you can `print` it to see the available services, methods, ports, and types.

**The following example is straight from the suds documentation.**

Example from suds site:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl'
client = Client(url) 
print client
```

Outputs this:

```
Suds - version: 0.3.7 build: (beta) R550-20090820

Service (BLZService) tns="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/"
   Prefixes (1)
     ns0 = "http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/"
   Ports (2):
     (soap)
       Methods (1):
         getBank(xs:string blz, )
     (soap12)
       Methods (1):
         getBank(xs:string blz, )
   Types (5):
      getBankType
      getBankResponseType
      getBankType
      getBankResponseType
      detailsType

Service (OtherBLZService) tns="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/"
   Prefixes (1)
     ns0 = "http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/"
   Ports (2):
     (soap)
       Methods (1):
         getBank(xs:string blz, )
     (soap12)
       Methods (1):
         getBank(xs:string blz, )
   Types (5):
      getBankType
      getBankResponseType
      getBankType
      getBankResponseType
      detailsType
```

Each service can be accessed in many ways, but here is a different port from each service qualified by method:

```
## service: BLZService, port: soap12, method: getBank
client.service['BLZService']['soap12'].getBank()
## service: OtherBLZService, port: soap, method: getBank
client.service['OtherBLZService']['soap'].getBank()
```

Is that the kind of thing you're working with?  If so, visit their documentation, which I think you'll find more than adequate.  If not, please consider adding as much detail as possible to your question to give us more to work with!

Comment: Actually what I was asking is how to modify endpoint (port) address on runtime. Your answer reminded me that this configuration can be in service description. And it was actually there.

client.service['BLZService'].setlocation()

Comment: Awesome, I'm really happy that I was able to help you.  Congrats! :)

Comment: Using suds 0.4 this is client.wsdl.services[0].setlocation(new_url)

Answer (score 4):

You can point the client to different endpoints via two methods:

1) client.set_options(location='http://path/to/your/wsdl') -or- 
2) using the client's clone() method. Then use set_options() again. It's really the same as #1 above but you end up with two clients to use, not one.

This latter method is a clean way to create a lightweight clone of your client object - they'll share the parsed wsdl and will only differ on their options, which you set via set_options().

I use both methods and they both work very well.

-Matt

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create a new Client object for each different URL.

Comment: But I'm passing WSDL url to Client constructor. What if WSDL and service have different URLs?

Comment: The WSDL should contain all the details of the service URL. You just need one client object per wsdl and you shouldn't need to worry about the service url (as a client)