# How to use SUDS with different WSDL and target address?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

My WSDL file is located in http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl and target where i should call methods is `http://192.168.0.33:8080/onvif/services`, how to configure `SUDS` client to use this two addresses?

Answer (score 1):

This post answers your question: [Changing web service url in SUDS library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670569/changing-web-service-url-in-suds-library)

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client('http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl') 
client.wsdl.services[0].setlocation('http://192.168.0.33:8080/onvif/services')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking to solve the same issue. I've came up with another solution that I find a bit more elegant than the one provided by Antti:

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client(
    'http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl',
    location='http://192.168.0.33:8080/onvif/services',
)
```